# (rust) how to replace Box<dyn T+'a> with more generic `AsRef`

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I'm newbe in Rust.

My task was to create function that converts `Iterator<&str>` , `Iterator<String>`, `Iterator<io::Result<String>>` to `Iterator<MyRecord>` for stream reading of large text files line by line and test it with simple `vec!["...","..."]`

After many hours of brain f**ng I solve it, but it's not very beautifull...

1. while no common trait `AsRef<str>` for `io::Result<String>` i defined own trait `StringRef` and implement it fo `&str`, `String` and `io::Result<String>`
2. i create struct for own iterator:

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<'a,S:StringRef> {
    lines: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=S> + 'a>,
}
```

and implement `Iterator<MyRecord>` on it.

All works fine. Mission complete.

But i'm still not satifacted with this code.

1. `Box` - may be should be better `AsRef`
2. `dyn XXX` - ma be better `<'a,S:StringRef, I> where I:Iterator...`

And i try to replace it with:

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<'a,S:StringRef> {
    lines: AsRef<dyn Iterator<Item=S> + 'a>,
}
```

not working - `error[E0782]: trait objects must include the` dyn `keyword`

Another try

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<'a,S:StringRef> {
    lines: dyn AsRef<dyn Iterator<Item=S> + 'a>,
}
```

not working - `expected trait object` dyn AsRef`, found struct` Box`, while where is AsRef trait for Box...

tryes generalize iterator:

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<'a,S:StringRef, I> where I:Iterator<Item = S> {
    lines: Box<I + 'a>,
}
```

not working - `not a trait`

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<'a,S:StringRef, I> where I:Iterator<Item = S> + 'a {
    lines: I,
}
```

catastrophic `unused parameter a,` , `unused parameter S` - why they are not used if I use them in where???

Please, who can explain - how to correctly generalize entity **some(AsRef)** reference to some (I) Iterator that iterates over some (S) StringRef trait ???

Instead of **Box** reference to some Iterator over some (S) String ref

really stucked...

Comment: Don't use `S`, just have `I` as generic and in the impl refer to `I::Item: StringRef`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```rust
struct ReaderIterator<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: StringRef,
{
    lines: I,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this fix it removes require to include explicit lifetime as additional bonus:

```
struct ReaderIterator<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item : StringRef,
{
    lines: I,
}
```

no more.

It's a kind of magic somehow, in Kotlin/Java/C# we have much more simple generic semantics